# How to keep two separate spreadsheets in sync, but only replacing updated values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to keep two separate spreadsheet in sync. I have been using the following methods that won't serve my purpose:

1- A simple IMPORTRANGE: this won't work because I have so much data that it fails constantly with a generic error

2- The following function has been working well, but the problem is that it removes all data first, which causes issues on how I'm using the data in the target spreadsheet:

```
function exportData() {

   // source doc ID
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  // target spreadsheet ID
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});
  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
  
}
```

So the solution I need for my needs is a script that will:

1. Look into the Target sheet and compare with the Source sheet
2. If the values in target cells are the same, do nothing
3. If the value in the target cell is not null and cell in source cell is null, do nothing
4. If the value in the target cell is different to the source cell, and source cell is not null, then replace that cell

Any suggestions how the script can be modified or if there's already an existing one you know that can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is just basic array manipulation. Consider taking a basic MDN arrays guide. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between your script and your 2 issues. And also, I cannot understand about `1. Look into the Target sheet and compare with the Source sheet`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: thanks Tanaike, absolutely! The script I posted is an option I used to keep two separate spreadsheets in sync, just like IMPORTRANGE. But I need to only update the cells that are updated: compare the target sheet (where cells need to be updated) and the source sheet to find differences in the cells. Once there's one cell that is different, I want the script to update that cell only. Hope that clarifies, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you are asking for can be achieved by comparing the array elements of the source and target value arrays against each other:**

```js
function exportData() {  
  // source doc ID
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  // target spreadsheet ID
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  //  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});
  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  var TRange = ts.getRange(A1Range);
  var TData =TRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(SData));
  if(JSON.stringify(TData)==JSON.stringify(SData)){
    Logger.log("Data did not change");
    return;
  }
  else{
    for(var i = 0; i < SData.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < SData[0].length; j++){
        if(SData[i][j]!=0 && SData[i][j]!=TData[i][j]){
          TRange.getCell(i+1, j+1).setValue(SData[i][j])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**However mind:
If you have much data, this approach will be slow.**

You might want to directl replace all imported data instead. For this it is not necessary to clear your whole sheet content - just overwrite the part tha is being imported:

```
function exportData() {
   // source doc ID
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  // target spreadsheet ID
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  // Do NOT clear the Google Sheet before copy

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData); 
}
```

Comment: amazing @ziganotschka ! this is exactly what I needed. Totally agree on your comment of making it replace the whole thing. But for this use case, I need your first approach which is perfect. Thanks so much!